# How to implement a grace period for Paypal subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In Stripe, when a subscription payment fails, the subscription's status is changed to `past_due` while Stripe makes a few attempts to charge the subscriber; if the last attempt also fails, then the subscription's status is changed to `canceled`. So, while the subscription is `past_due`, I know it's on a grace period, and I can invite the user to pay for the subscription as soon as possible before their subscription is definitively canceled.

How can the above be achieved with Paypal? From what I understand, when the next due payment fails, the subscription remains `active` while Paypal makes two more attempts to charge the subscriber, five days apart from each. So, if a subscription is due on May 14, and the payment fails, Paypal retries on May 19 and one more time on May 24; at that point, the subscription's status (which has been `active` during these 10 days) is changed to `suspended` (not `canceled`).

I have read that Paypal sends a BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED webhook when subscription payments fail. This webhook includes a `next_payment_retry_date` that tells me when Paypal will retry charging the subscriber, and I have read that, when the webhook is sent for the last failed attempt (the one made on the 10th day), `next_payment_retry_date` will be set to `null`. So, my idea is to listen to BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED and mark the user's subscription's as `past_due` when I get this webhook, unless the webhook's `next_payment_retry_date` is set to `null`: in that case, I can cancel the subscription via API and mark the user's subscription as `canceled`.

Can anyone confirm that this is a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only event you need to listen for is PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED. Use this event to update your system's valid through date, whatever it may be, including whatever grace period you may wish to incorporate. If you do not receive a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event in time, the subscription has lapsed and will stay lapsed until and unless you receive a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event at which point you could reactivate it in the same fashion and using the same logic.

That is all you need to do.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to add the grace period to next payment date when saving the subcription's details (in this case I would save May 24 and not May 14 as the next payment date). This is a good start, thank you for the tip. However, if I save May 24 then the cron job that would cancel the user's subscription in my app would run on May 25, meaning the user gets 10 extra days of use because during those extra 10 days his subscription continues to be active, right? Sorry if I'm nitpicking, I'm just trying to cover all cases!